# extraReducers builder.addCase rejected state not showing Using Redux Thunk With Redux Toolkit With Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a POST request to an endpoint with React. On fulfilled state of my `builder.addCase` reducer, my data is generated or return back to me when fulfilled, but on rejected state of my `builder.addCase` reducer, checking my Redux Dev Tools, no rejected state is found even though I have an error. Rather the error message that ought to be in rejected state is found or populated to fulfilled state. Checking Redux Dev Tools I can only find pending and fulfilled state, rejected state is nowhere to be found.

Here is my code:

```
export const userRegisterAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/register",
  async (user: User, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/users/register",
        user,
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Here is my slice:

```
const usersSlices = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    userAuth: "login",
    registered: {},
    loading: false,
    Error: ""
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.registered = payload
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
    })
  }
});

export default usersSlices.reducer;
```

Here is where I dispatch my action.

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch(); 
   
export interface User {
  firstName : string;
  password : string;
  lastName: string;
  email : string;
}

export const Signup = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [passwordFieldType, setPasswordFieldType] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [name]: value.trim()
    });
  }

  const handleInputSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = user;

    if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !password) {
      return toast.error(
        "Please, fill up all inputs !!!",
        {
          toastId: "fill_inputs", 
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          autoClose: 1000,
        }
      );
    }

    const response = await dispatch(userRegisterAction({
      firstName,
      email,
      password,
      lastName
    }))
  }
}
```

I have tried everything I could, but to no avail. I've checked online too, no related help or answer to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same challenge a few minutes ago. For me, it was because I did not add "return" before my "rejectWithValue"; which prevented my "rejected" from working because the function is a promise which has three states. And whenever you are working with a promise, always return your response.
For you, you need to parse "error.response.data" instead of only "error" in your reject function and update the state "Error" with the rejected action. See the implementation below.

The previous implementation of the userRegisterAction function

```
export const userRegisterAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/register",
  async (user: User, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/users/register",
        user,
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

The new implementation of the userRegisterAction function

```
export const userRegisterAction = createAsyncThunk(
      "users/register",
      async (user: User, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:5000/api/users/register",
            user,
          );
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          return rejectWithValue(error.response.data); //This carries the response you are receiving from the server
        }
      }
    );
```

Previous implementation of the usersSlice

```
const usersSlices = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    userAuth: "login",
    registered: {},
    loading: false,
    Error: ""
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.registered = payload
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
    })
  }
});

export default usersSlices.reducer;
```

New implementation of usersSlice

```
const usersSlices = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    userAuth: "login",
    registered: {},
    loading: false,
    Error: ""
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.registered = payload
    })

    builder.addCase(userRegisterAction.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.Error = payload; // Note: I updated the state here
    })
  }
});

export default usersSlices.reducer;
```

I hope this helps you resolve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `throw error.response.data;` in catch (error) of createAsyncThunk and in .rejected i set `state.error = action.error.message;`